# Select to display text file php html

Tags: php, html, text-files, display

100% newbie here. :)
Been searching on google but i cant find any complete solution.
So what i wanted to do is to display row of files name for example

[image]

text1

text2

text3
....
when clicked it show the text content of it.

So far i can get the list of the files from the directory i wanted:

```
$dir_path = "files$row[CardID]/";
foreach(glob($dir_path.'*') as $file) {
    $nname = substr($file, strpos($file,"/")+1);
    echo $nname."<br>"; /* this returns me text1 text2 text3 */
};
```

So my question is how do i make it to show the text content when click on it(popup or html page or ....i got no idea)?
Very appreciate for any help

Comment: The solutions is in the comment @Clyv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
if(!isset($_GET['file'])) {
die('Please input a file');
}
$file = stripslashes($_GET['file']);
echo file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
```

Or to just include a directory:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach (glob("txt_include/*.txt") as $filename)
{
    echo '<li><a href="?file=' . $filename . '">' . $filename . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i got it to display a link that i can click but when i click it loading for .1s then nothing appears. 
How do i implement file_get_content upon click? Thanks

Comment: Sorry my first code wasn't clear. Try https://hastebin.com/anoxaforog.bash

Answer (score 0):

Use database. Example (it's not finished, sorry, I'm not pro on these things yet)

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'USER', 'PASS', 'DATABASE');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM topic ORDER BY `id` DESC';  
$rqt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($rqt))
    $text1 = $data['text']

echo $text1;
```

Comment: After I indented your code I realized you probably meant to call the `$text1` assignement and the `echo` on each iteration, so you'd probably want them wrapped in curly braces `{}`.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using mysql_, ever. Use SQLi if you're going to do databases however the sender stated they wanted to use flatfile.